# Use single JavaScript file for updating design in 2 HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying this just for curiosity purpose, first I will explain what I'm thinking.

right now I have 2 HTML file 1. firsthtml.html and 2. secondhtml.html, for this both HTML files I have a single javascript file of main.js, now the question is when I click the button on the firsthtml.html page it will call the AJAX function and AJAX process will begin. at the success function of AJAX I used to update the secondhtml.html, I tried to find this way, but it's not working.
here's my code.

firsthtml.html

```
<form  id="form">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="file" class="form-group" id="share_img" name="share_img">
    <input   type="text" class="form-group" name="val1">
    <input  type="text" class="form-group" name="val2">
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="submit" id="send_file" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>           
 </div>
</form>

<script src="../../main.js"></script>
```

secondhtml.html

```
<div id="came_from" style="display: none; height: 30px; width: 30px; background-color: black"></div>
<script src="../../main.js"></script>
```

and here is my js file for both

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
       url: "/store_file",
       type: "POST",
       data:  new FormData(this),
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       processData:false,
       beforeSend : function()
        {
            $("#err").fadeOut();
        },
       success: function(response)
      {
            console.log(response);
            $('#came_from').show();
      },
    });
   }));
 });

//this I wrote for checking

$('#send_file').on('click', function(){
  console.warn('check in secondhtml.html'); //this is only visible in firsthtml.html
 })
```

As per code all events are fired by the firsthtml.html, so I'm getting output in the only firsthtml.html, that is not affecting in secondhtml.html. Is it possible to do as I'm thinking?

Comment: `secondhtml.html` doesn't exist when you load firsthtml in your browser. Then when you navigate to second it knows nothing about what happened in first unless you pass data through the url or use localStorage

Comment: hi @charlietfl thank you for your comment, as I studied localstorage use to store data in local computer only, what about if I use my application in 2 different computers ex: firsthtml.html opened in mine own PC and secondhtml.html will be opened in someone else. is that gone work?

Comment: May you can use [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)  function to load content of `secondhtml` in `firsthtml`  ?

Comment: You would need a remote data storage if you want to keep state data for various devices/browsers and load that stored data using ajax

Comment: hi @Swati this is quite interesting let me try

Comment: @charlietfl remote storage means like database?

Comment: Database or cloud storage service such as firebase

Comment: @charlietfl except database or cloud storage is their no any other options?

Comment: @CodeBug You need a mechanism to sync the data on firstpage&client with a secondpage&client. A webserver (Apache, IIS, Etc) is a common tool for this. The firstpage&client sends the data to the server where it is stored (database, cloudstorage, xml, etc). When the data is updated you need to notify the secondpage&client that there is new data available (by Polling, WebSockets, etc.) Long story short, you have a lot of options all with there own pros and cons.

Comment: hi @MarkBaijens thanks for your ans, actually I was trying to build something like websokets  only.

Comment: @CodeBug If you want to do that and communicate from client to client than I think you can't not do that with the most commen browsers due to security issues (although i never looked into that). But even if you are able to do that you would need a client with a static ip and a port that is reachable from the other client (so correct port forwarding on an internal network). It will be easier with desktop applications but even then you need to setup the network correctly.

Comment: @MarkBaijens okay, this suggestion was more helpful.